# imagenes se desordenan al ponerles titulo o texto html

Tags: html, css

```
<table>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<a href="" class="mainmenu" /><img title="Overlord" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-wmXOMSvGdqE/W1olljMPl8I/AAAAAAAAASE/zcrXBcEDR5Q72zGVf24_41unNrU-fE7DACEwYBhgL/w140-h87-p/HALF_LIFE_3_WALLPAPERS_IN_HD.jpg"  alt="" HSPACE="20"></a>
</tr>
<tr>
<a href="" class="mainmenu" /><img title="Overlord" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-wmXOMSvGdqE/W1olljMPl8I/AAAAAAAAASE/zcrXBcEDR5Q72zGVf24_41unNrU-fE7DACEwYBhgL/w140-h87-p/HALF_LIFE_3_WALLPAPERS_IN_HD.jpg"  alt="" HSPACE="20"></a>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

El problema es que tengo ordenadas las imagenes de forma horizontal, se encuentran con un hover, todo perfecto. Pero al momento de intentar agregarle un texto debajo ya sea mediante `<p>` o  `<h1,h2,etc>` entre otros que intentado, mis imagenes quedan en posición vertical, la verdad no se porque pasa pero al momento de internar ponerle un titulo o encabezado debajo, pasan de horizontal a vertical. Ayuda por favor.

Comment: Que interesante tu pregunta, pero lo seria aun mas si posteas tu codigo para que la comunidad te pueda ayudar eficientemente.

Comment: agrega tu codigo

Comment: ya eh colocado el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si te has equivocado al poner tu código o lo tenías de esa forma, pero tu tabla está mal compuesta, cierras etiquetas que no se ve donde se abren si es que se abren, te faltan `td`, añades el / en el `a` donde no debes y abres el primer tr mal. Además de que el problema que comentas es porque en vez de los `tr` del medio tendrías que tener `td`, corrigiendo los errores de composición y añadiendo los `td` tu tabla tendría que quedar así, con los `p` mostrándose correctamente:

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
<a href="" class="mainmenu"><img title="Overlord" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-wmXOMSvGdqE/W1olljMPl8I/AAAAAAAAASE/zcrXBcEDR5Q72zGVf24_41unNrU-fE7DACEwYBhgL/w140-h87-p/HALF_LIFE_3_WALLPAPERS_IN_HD.jpg"  alt="" HSPACE="20"></a>
<p>fffffffffffffff</p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="" class="mainmenu"><img title="Overlord"                     src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-wmXOMSvGdqE/W1olljMPl8I/AAAAAAAAASE/zcrXBcEDR5Q72zGVf24_41unNrU-fE7DACEwYBhgL/w140-h87-p/HALF_LIFE_3_WALLPAPERS_IN_HD.jpg"  alt="" HSPACE="20"></a>
<p>fffffffffffffff</p>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, me sirvio de mucho